# Installing Cordova Plugin on Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I am trying to install this cordova package in my meteor package:

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase

so i run this command from the CLI

meteor add cordova:cc.fovea.cordova.purchase@https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase.git#79449b8c20c137cfe2fc785d250aa4b92c1c425e

The installation works, but everytime i try to refrence this package from the code i get a Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined

Here is the code i am using:

[Client side Code]

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
   store.register({
   id:    "10stars",
   alias: "10 Stars",
   type:  store.CONSUMABLE
  });
});
```

Am i running the installation correctly, or am i missing a step?

Comment: can you confirm if the plugin you've installed was loaded into your app?

Comment: How would i do that? I don't see where it adds the files, i checked .meteor/local/cordova-build/plugins there is no folder, but i tried to manually add the folder with the contents from git and still no luck :S

Comment: if you are developing on android, you can check its AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: nope nothing of interest in there